# Unauthorized curl for parse.com on mac

Tags: java, macos, curl, parse-platform, parse-server

I am working on a java project that communicates to a parse database that is online.
But the problem is following curl command:

```
curl -X GET \
-H "X-Parse-Application-Id: ApplicationID" \
-H "X-Parse-Master-Key: MasterKey" \
http://0.0.0.0:1337/parse/classes/testClass
```

When i execute this command from my windows pc i get all the rows from my test class. But when i execute it from my macbook i get:

```
{"error":"unauthorized"}
```

I am using the same code on my windows and mac and i am connecting to the same parse server.

This is also the exact same curl command I get when i go to my parse dashboard and click on Export to Curl in the API Console. When i execute it from my dashboard it also works.

When i try to execute the curl command through my terminal I am able to get the row's.

But i use the same curl in my code:

```
String curl = "curl -X GET \\\n" +
                "-H \"X-Parse-Application-Id: ApplicationID\" \\\n" +
                "-H \"X-Parse-Master-Key: MasterKey\" \\\n" +
                "http://0.0.0.0:1337/parse/classes/testClass";

        Process curlProc;
        String outputString = null;
        try {
            curlProc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(curl);

            DataInputStream curlIn = new DataInputStream(
                    curlProc.getInputStream());

            String retrievedJson = "";

            while ((outputString = curlIn.readLine()) != null) {
                retrievedJson = outputString;
                System.out.print("RETRIEVED JSON: "+outputString+" \n");
            }
```

Comment: do you know parse has SDK for Java?.... are you using some Ip address of the server or you are using 0.0.0.0? Can you ping the parse server IP from both machines?

Comment: Yes i am able to ping the server from both machines, and i am using the ip of the server. I also found out now that there is something wrong with the curl command that is being executed from the mac. When i print the curl out and past it in the terminal it works and goes to the server with the correct headers (found out through a proxy). But the curl that is being executed from java doesn't has any headers but it makes separate get request to the value of the headers. If we take the value of the example in the question it sends http get requests to "http: //ApplicationID..."

Comment: "http: //MasterKey" and to "http: //0.0.0.0:1337/parse/classes/testClass".
All after executing one curl command.